# OSError: Can't read data (file read failed:...error message = 'Input/output error'...)

Tags: google-colaboratory, hdf5, oserror

I want to read a HDF5 file from Colab which is hosted from my Google Drive. This file size is massive (46 GB). But while working with the file, the following error is produced:

```
OSError: Can't read data (file read failed: time = Sun May 10 08:31:46 2020
, filename = 'gdrive/My Drive/Computer_vision_with_deep_learning/fruits-ml-web-app/hdf5/features.hdf', file descriptor = 62, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x9efd83080, total read size = 32918392704, bytes this sub-read = 32918392704, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 4097052672)
```

It can open the file but while reading the error is thrown.

I found a thread regarding the issue on GitHub. Following is the link of it:

[Reading file from Drive giving OSError #559](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/559)

Why this is happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the file to `/content` fisrt. It may help.